# jQuery Ajax call in an unexpected loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm developing an application where I load content using ajax calls. But in a certain situation, I get an ajax call on a loop but it ends in random iterations. Below is the sequential code from the a double click event to the final ajax call.

```
//I use the double click event to fire the function
$('.item-container').on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    var posX = e.pageX;
    var posY = e.pageY;
    var element = $(this);
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var dblclick = parseInt($(that).data('double'), 10);
        if (dblclick > 0) {
            $(that).data('double', dblclick-1);
        } else {
            showToolTip(posX,posY,element);
        }
    }, 300);
}).on('dblclick', '.item', function(e) {
    $(this).data('double', 2);
    addItemsToBill(this);
});


function addItemsToBill(selectedItem) {


var element = null;

$(".bill-item-list").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("display") == "block") {
        element = $(this);
        return;
    }
});

if (element == null) {
    getSystemMessage(BILL_SELECT_VALIDATION_MSG);
    return;
}

if ($('#open-tab .bill-list').find(".bill-item-list").length == 0
        && $(element).find('.bill-item').length == 0) {
    getSystemMessage(BILL_SELECT_VALIDATION_MSG);
    return;
}

var bill = $('.sample-elements').find('.bill-item');
var clone = bill.clone();
var itemId = $(selectedItem).attr('id');
var billId = $(element).parent().attr('id');

if ($(selectedItem).attr('isopen') == '1') {

    $('.open-item-popup-overlay').lightbox_me( {
        centered : true,
        destroyOnClose : false,
    });

    $('.itmRate').val('');
    $('#itmAmt').html('0.00');
    $('.itemQty').text('1');

    $('.itm-cancel').click(function() {
        $('.open-item-popup-overlay').trigger('close');
    });

            //when the first run goes it's fine, bt after that, the looping starts from here. I double checked whether there is another code segment which fires this but there are none.
    $('.itm-ok').click(function(){
        if ($('.itmRate').val() == "") {
            getSystemMessage(AMOUNT_INPUT);
            return;
        }
                    //This function gets iterated multiple times if I run the same event for multiple times.
                    //The function is only used in this two locations and no any other places.
        billItemDrop(itemId, billId, clone, selectedItem, null,element, 1, true);
        return false;
    })

} else {
    billItemDrop(itemId, billId, clone, selectedItem, null, element, 0,true);
}
}

function billItemDrop(itemId, billId, billItemClone, doubleClickedItem,draggableHelper, catchElement, isOpen, isDoubleClick) {

var openItemQuantity =  stringToDouble($('.itemQty').val());
var openItemRate = stringToDouble($('.itmRate').val());
var openItemAmount = openItemQuantity * openItemRate;

var ajaxObject = 'itemId=' + itemId + '&billId=' + billId + '&qty='
        + openItemQuantity + '&rate=' + openItemRate + '&openItem='
        + isOpen;

ajaxCall(ADD_ITEM_TO_BILL,AJAX_POST,ajaxObject,function(response) {

            var responseObject = response.billDetail;
            var billTotal = responseObject.billTotal;

            var total = response.billDetail.rate * response.billDetail.qty;

            // Add Items to the bill failed
            if (response.status != "success") {
                getSystemMessage(ADD_ITEM_TO_PRINTED_BILL);
                return;
            }

            billItemClone.attr('itemId', responseObject.itemId);
            billItemClone.attr('billDetailId', responseObject.billDetailId);

            billItemClone.find('.bill-item-name').text(
                    responseObject.itemName);
            billItemClone.find('.bill-item-rate span').text(
                    responseObject.rate.toFixed(2));
            billItemClone.find('.bill-item-amount').text(
                    total.toFixed(2));
            billItemClone.find('.bill-item-qty span').text(responseObject.qty);

            if (responseObject.kotBotNo != null) {
                billItemClone.find('.kot-bot-num').text(
                        responseObject.kotBotNo);
            }

            billItemClone.draggable( {
                revert : false,
                addClasses : false,
                zIndex : 1,
                containment : "window",
                opacity : 0.5,
                cursor : "move",
                scroll : false,
                helper : function() {
                    return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').show();
                }
            });

            if (isDoubleClick == true
                    && (doubleClickedItem != undefined
                            || doubleClickedItem != null || doubelClickedItem != "")) {
                billItemClone.find('.bill-item-img img').attr('src',
                        $(doubleClickedItem).css('background-image'));
            } else if (isDoubleClick == false
                    && (draggableHelper != undefined
                            || drdraggableHelper != null || draggableHelper != "")) {
                billItemClone.find('.bill-item-img img').attr('src',
                        draggableHelper.css('background-image'));
            }

            if (catchElement.height() > 300) {
                catchElement.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
                catchElement.css('height', '320px');
            }

            if (catchElement.find('.bill-item').length == 0) {
                billItemClone.insertBefore(
                        catchElement.find('.item-drop-point')).hide()
                        .fadeIn("slow");
            } else {
                billItemClone.insertBefore(
                        catchElement.find('.bill-item').first()).hide()
                        .fadeIn("slow");
            }

            catchElement.parent().find('.amount')
                    .html(billTotal.toFixed(2));

            if (draggableHelper != undefined || draggableHelper != null) {
                draggableHelper.hide('fade', function() {
                    draggableHelper.remove()
                });
            }

            $('.item-drop-point').removeClass('item-drop-hover');

        },false);
}

/**
 * 
 * Function for ajax calls - url : webservice url - type : ajax call type - data :
 * data that needs to be passed - callback : function that needs to be executed
 * 
 * when ajax call succeed
 * 
 * @param url
 * @param type
 * @param data
 * @param callback
 */
function ajaxCall(url, type, data, callback,async){

// Assign default value to async if its not specified
if (async===undefined) async = true;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    dataType : "json",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(x){
    if(x && x.overrideMimeType){
        x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
    async : async,
    success:callback
});
}
```

The function gets iterated so the ajax call gets iterated too. I used break points to track the iteration but from the point of the click event I couldn't locate where it get's triggered after the first click event. 
Is there anything wrong in the code which makes the function iterate. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `addItemsToBill(this);` you are adding new event handlers to `$('.itm-ok')`

Try removing the call to `billItemDrop(itemId, billId, clone, selectedItem, null,element, 1, true);` and replacing it with a `console.log('Test'` If you find that multiple console logs are being made every time you click the issue is that every click is being handled by multiple handlers. If that is the case and you really want to use this structure you will have to unbind you click handler before rebinding it.

```
$('.itm-ok').off('click')
$('.itm-ok').on('click',function(){
        if ($('.itmRate').val() == "") {
            getSystemMessage(AMOUNT_INPUT);
            return;
        }
                    //This function gets iterated multiple times if I run the same event for multiple times.
                    //The function is only used in this two locations and no any other places.
        billItemDrop(itemId, billId, clone, selectedItem, null,element, 1, true);
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: And you are a genius! :) Thanks man... it works! I bind the click even multiple times!